# Issue with SQLLOCALDB

Tags: windows, azure, emulation, storage

When in try to start azure storage emulator i get the following error.

Probing Failed. Retrying probe for localDB
Probing SQL Instance: '(localdb)\v11.0'.
Caught exception while probing for SQL endpoint. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - LocalDB error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
)
Number of SqlErrors Reported: 1
SqlError: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - LocalDB error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
)
LocalDB is installed but is not functioning properly. You may be missing prerequisites. Make sure you have .NET 4.0.2 or higher installed.
No SQL Instance found.

One or more initialization actions have failed. Resolve these errors before attempting to run the storage emulator again. Please refer to go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=248088 for more details.

I installed .net 4.0.2 also. I tried uninstalling and installing sqllocaldb as well.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
After installing .NET framework 4.5, the problem is gone for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same kind of problem when reinitializing Storage Emulator. I used "Autodetect" parameter at command prompt and it worked for me.

DSInit /sqlinstance:(localdb)\v11.0 /Autodetect /ForceCreate

Hope this help to you too.

Amit

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can check again if local DB is correctly installed and started. Please refer to [SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx) for more information.